# Need help on getting characters from a string?

Tags: c++, string

I'm currently in an Intro C++ class, and I'm learning about Strings and Member Functions of them.
I have questions that are like this:

Assume that  name is a variable of type  string that has been assigned a value. Write an expression whose value is a  string containing the first character of the value of  name . So if the value of  name were "Smith" the expression's value would be "S".

or

Assume that  name is a variable of type  string that has been assigned a value. Write an expression whose value is a  string containing the last character of the value of  name . So if the value of  name were "Smith" the expression's value would be "h".

or

Assume that  word is a variable of type  string that has been assigned a value. Write an expression whose value is a  string consisting of the last three characters of the value of  word . So if the value of  word were "biggest" the expression's value would be "est".

I know things like name[0] and name[name.length() - 1], but I don't know how to turn those into a string in one expression. I've been looking for a table or list of member functions that can help me do this, but I'm stuck. Any directions or aid would be great. :D

Comment: Look at the string constructor.

Comment: And also have a look at the `substr` method of the `string` class

Comment: homework ! homework ! homework! :P sry but i couldn't resist this comment :). Btw, substring would be the method u are looking for (as pointed by Dan).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the substr method.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Perfect :D helped a bundles. I feel silly not stumbling on this before. >.<

Answer (score 2):

I would use substring:

```
//assume that the string in question is held in a variable with the name str
string s1 = str.substr(0,1);
string s2 = str.substr(str.length() - 2, 1);
string s3 = str.substr(str.length() = 4, 3);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: There's a typo in your `s3` expression; and in both your `s2` and your `s3` expressions, you can leave out the second argument, since it defaults to `npos` (i.e., "until the end of the string").

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few number of ways to do it. For instance, an `std::string` is also a standard container of `char`. So you could begin with an empty string, and append one `char` to it.